# How to get a distinct result from a single column and array from another with eloquent?

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel, eloquent, record

I currently have 2 columns, one with user_id's and another with ratings. I want to end up with distinct results for my user_id's and have a corresponding array of ratings for each dinstinct user_id.

[image]

In this case I would want to end up with 3 arrays of 51, 52 and 53 that has a nested array of the ratings for each rating record that specific user_id has.

Is this doable or do I just need to grab all my results and work it out in php?

Comment: Were either of our answers able to help you or are you looking for something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a user table/Model.

```
// using userRating to reference your table as you didnt give the table/model name
$userRating = User::has("userRating")->with("userRating")->get();
```

This wil give you what you want and also give you only users with rating.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly typical [One to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship. You have one user that has many ratings. You should have a Rating model which uses the table in your post and a User model which has its own table. Then set up your models with these relationships.

Rating Model:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

User Model:

```
public function ratings() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Rating');
}
```

Then if you want to get the list of all users and nested arrays of their ratings, you could use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to display the results like this:

```
 $users = User::with('ratings')->all();
```